# What's the name of this style of chart that splits flows?

Tags: terminology, chart-design

Does anyone know what the name of this style chart that shows a flow and has parts splitting off along the x axis?

[image]

Comment: This chart type is used in/used to visualize US government budget, too.

Answer (score 7):

This is called a [Sankey Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram).

Comment: Hi, welcome back.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks! I never left—there's just so few questions that are not graphic software related that I hardly find any to answer :D

Comment: Wow thank you so much!

Comment: @Chelsey FYI if an post answers your question you can click the check mark next to the answer to indicate so. That gives reputation to both you and the person who made the post.